# civilization 5 domination victory capturing capitals

Tags: civilization-5, civilization-5-gods-and-kings

So I was reading the in-game help on how to achieve a domination victory, and I got a little confused.

It said something about the last civilization possessing their original capital is the winner. Something about "if you capture 3 of your enemies capitals, and the 5th player sneaks in and captures your capital while you're not looking, they are the winner and not you."

This makes sense except it counteracts what I thought I had learned from playing the game. I thought that you couldn't capture a civilization's capital unless you had captured all their cities first? But maybe it's that you can't capture their LAST capital unless you had captured all their cities first?

Kind of a civ newb, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you capture someone's capital, their capital is temporarily relocated to another city.  But it is the original capital that is important for the victory condition.  You are not allowed to destroy it, so you need to be able to hold on to it until you are the only one that still controls your original capital.

Comment: alright, well maybe my problem is my interpretation of "capture". how do you capture another civilization's capital? I thought you had to attack it all the way down to 0 and have your troops move in, but one time when I was playing I was told I couldn't do that to their capital because they still had cities I didn't control..

Comment: @Josh Your definition of capture is correct. You attack it until it is down to 0 hitpoints and then you move in with a military unit. I can not recall not being able to conquer the capital ever.

Comment: hmmm... alright. i wish there was some way to test this? im positive I was trying to take out england and it wouldn't let me conquer london, and im almost positive it said something about them having other cities.. ill check it out. thanks.